# Google map showing developer mode only?

Tags: google-maps, google-api

Google map showing developer only how to fix it?

[Google map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ws5X0.png)

[Map api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ga9UK.png)

[Map api code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9SdE.png)

Comment: You need to add a valid API key to the request for the API.

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps is no longer free. You have to associate a credit card so that you can get billed if your site has requests that exceed the $200 credit they give you monthly for free. That is why you get the watermarked maps.

For more information, see: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/

Update: A common problem with the new billing system is that you now have to activate each API separately. They all have different pricing (some are even free), so Google makes a point of having you enable them individually for your domain. I was never a heavy user of Google Maps, but I get the feeling that there are many more APIs now than there used to be.

So if you're still getting a restricted usage message after you've enabled billing, find out what API you need exactly for the features you want to offer, and check if it's enabled. The API settings are annoyingly hard to find.

1. Go to this link: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard.
2. Then you select your project in the dropdown.
3. Go to library on the left pane.
4. Browse the available APIs and enable the one you need.